# Aligning Right in Ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, alignment

I always seem to have aligning problems with CSS.

There's many different methods of aligning right, but none of the techniques I usually do work.

I don't want to use margin with % value either.

trying to get this checkmark to align right.

[image]

.HTML

```
    <ion-item>
      <span>
        Every Sunday
      </span>
      <ion-icon class="right" name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
    </ion-item>
```

.CSS

```
.right{
   float:right;
   text-align: right;
}
```

EDIT: Found it was Ionic feature preventing other CSS aligning it.

So `slot="end"` did the trick in the .HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write css for it. Ionic framework already has solution of this.
There exist **slot** property in Ionic which has **start and end** value.

you need to put **slot="end"** on **ion-icon**.

```
<ion-item>
    <span>
      Every Sunday
    </span>
    <ion-icon slot="end" class="right" name="checkmark"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
```

[image]
Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

i hope i understood your question/intention correctly. try adding the following rules for you `ion-item` class:

```
    width: 100%; /* or whatever you want the reference element to be */
    display: inline-block;
```

this will make the element you are aligning on the right (`right`) do the same - but the width of the reference element (`ion-item`) has changed.

Comment: I added this as a class called "parent-right" for ion-item. 
However, this did not solve the issue.
The checkmark still aligns left.

Comment: also if you change `width` to some non-relative value, let's say `500px`?

Comment: yeah I changed the 100% to 500px and it still didn't work.

Comment: hm, and you're sure the rules aren't overwritten by other css rules (add `important` to check)?